# Cucumber doesn't generate steps properly

Tags: cucumber, regression, bdd

I'm very new to BDD and cucumber testing. I have tried to combine BDD cucumber testing with Rest Assured and I'm facing some issues and need your help

I have a very simple feature file

```
Feature: End to end test for add category feature

  Scenario Outline:Successful addition of a new category
    When I try to add a category with request file <requestFile>
    Then I receive HTTP status <status>
    And The response matches response from file <responseFile>
    Examples:
      | requestFile                                               | status | responseFile
      | "json-files/category/requests/category.json"              | 201    | "json-files/common/expected-responses/requestSuccessfullyProcessed.json"
      | "json-files/category/requests/category-name-missing.json" | 400    | "json-files/category/expected-responses/category-name-missing.json"
```

My plan is very simple. I have a pair of a request and a response file and I'm performing end-to-end regression testing.

It's throwing an error in the last step where it's supposed to validate the response file saying step undefined. When I uncommented my step definition methods and tried to let cucumber generate the steps I noticed that this is what it is generating

```
Step undefined
You can implement this step and 2 other step(s) using the snippet(s) below:

@When("I try to add a category with request file {string}")
public void i_try_to_add_a_category_with_request_file(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("I receive HTTP status {int}")
public void i_receive_http_status(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("The response matches response from file <responseFile>")
public void the_response_matches_response_from_file_response_file() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

Notice that the last method somehow didn't generate the {string} argument and this is the reason even when I define the steps, it's not working.

I have no clue if I have made any mistakes in the feature file. A bit of help would be great

Comment: Try adding a `|` at the end of each table row. The parser should have complained about the missing `|` though. You should be report that as a bug.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Thank you so much. That was the issue. Really appreciate the help. There was no clue in the error logs what the problem was in the feature file. Will report it. Thanks again....!!

Comment: Also, needs to add double quotes if it is string. Sometimes it generates rubbish methods otherwise.